What do gcc -Wabi-tag warn me for and how should I avoid that
When enabling -Wabi-tag I get the warning when trying to return std::string (by value). What is the purpose of this warning, ie what harm could ignore it lead to?
What options are there for avoiding this warning? I guess that I could add the abi tag to my function, but that appears somewhat ugly and might propagate through the codebase (I'm afraid). I'm thinking that using C++11+ should mean an appropriate ABI throughout anyway.
Example:
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#define CXX11_ABI // __attribute__ ((abi_tag("cxx11")))

CXX11_ABI
std::string hello();

CXX11_ABI
std::string hello() // <- warns here
{
    return "Hello, world";
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << hello() << std::endl;
}

The warning reads (yes I've also enablde -Werror):
 error: ‘std::string hello()’ inherits the "cxx11" ABI tag that ‘std::string’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’} (used in its return type) has [-Werror=abi-tag]

My wondering is a bit because in above example if I comment in the out commented definition of CX11_ABI the warning disappears, but the emitted assembler code is identical (including a "cxx11" tag on the hello function name).
It is mentioned that there could be a problem if linking with code emitted by pre C++11 version of gcc, but that would only mean that it wouldn't link, right?

From gcc's docs:

The abi_tag attribute can be applied to a function, variable, or class declaration. It modifies the mangled name of the entity to incorporate the tag name, in order to distinguish the function or class from an earlier version with a different ABI; perhaps the class has changed size, or the function has a different return type that is not encoded in the mangled name.
The -Wabi-tag flag enables a warning about a class which does not have all the ABI tags used by its subobjects and virtual functions; for users with code that needs to coexist with an earlier ABI, using this option can help to find all affected types that need to be tagged.
When a type involving an ABI tag is used as the type of a variable or return type of a function where that tag is not already present in the signature of the function, the tag is automatically applied to the variable or function. -Wabi-tag also warns about this situation; this warning can be avoided by explicitly tagging the variable or function or moving it into a tagged inline namespace.

You only have to care about this if you are linking to code compiled by a different version of gcc. If your build process is compiling everything from scratch, it does not matter to you, and you should disable this warning.
In the specific case of std::string, prior to C++11, gcc used a different implementation, which was unable to meet the new requirements for std::string that were made in C++11.

But what if I later "accidentally" link it with code compiled with a later version of GCC? To me it looks like the compiler adds the tag implicitely and warns about that.

@skyking Later gcc? you'll be fine (unless the standard makes another breaking change). It's specifically the change from C++98 to C++11 where gcc had to change the internals of std::string because new requirements were impossible under their previous implementation

I meant earlier gcc version...

My point is this is a warning specific to separate compilation on gcc. In the vast majority of projects, you shouldn't have this warning on. It is for a niche situation which is already within behaviour undefined by the C++ standard.

Some further investigation shows that adding the cxx11 abi tag makes the warning go away, but if there's a problem it would remain. By the way, things within behaviour undefined by the C++ standard is a great deal of what to warn about.

@skyking Linking object files from different compiler versions is the thing undefined by the standard. This is only one of the things you have to worry about if you do. You don't need to add these tags because you should not mix compilers

Let us continue this discussion in chat.


for users with code that needs to coexist with an earlier ABI, using this option can help to find all affected types that need to be tagged

That's literally it.
Are you writing code that uses a later ABI but needs to be linked together with code that uses an earlier ABI? If not, don't enable the warning. If yes, congratulations, you are probably writing libstdc++.
